# Before I was using Twitter API version 1.1 but now it has stopped working. I moved to version 2 but not able get tweets in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter

I created project in Twitter developer account. I have all consumer and access token keys. I tried but I get an error

> TwitterQueryException: You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product

I also tried with POSTMAN API but still not working.